# Titanium Studio - Trying to run example app

Tags: android, titanium

I'm newbie in Titanium Studio and I have some weird questions:
- When I choose a new Mobile Project and trying to Run under the Android SDK Emulator,
I able to see the phone screen but when I'm going in the emulator to the apps list, I cant see the application I just created...

any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: well it works here on both mac and windows. Please give some more information

Comment: Well, when I'm clicking on "Run" The Android SDK Emulator been opened and show me "my phone". but for some reason when I clicked on "Apps" to see all my apps, I cant find the app I develop.. I think I need first to install the app, the questions is how?

Answer (score 0):

When you hit *Run* it is automatically installed in your device/emulator.

Be sure it was successfully installed in your emulator first, please see:

> **Android troubleshooting**
>
> The initial launch of the Android emulator can be quite slow and Studio may timeout before it can install and launch the application. If this happens just click Run in Studio again. Subsequent launches should not time out on the same virtual device.
>
> http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Creating_Your_First_Titanium_Apps-section-37541502_CreatingYourFirstTitaniumApps-AddaTableView